# Best model field for product details? In django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am making an ecommerce website in django. I am facing with a problem. Can you tell me what is the best way or model field for product details??? please Help!
Thank in advance

Comment: Can you exactly specify the problem or what didn't work for you?

Comment: I wanted to know which model field is the best for product details and characteristics? For example, if my product is phone it's storage, it's CPU and other details. So, how can I print this information. Do I have to make specific model field for each details?

Comment: I don't have enough experience, that's why I am having such kind of problems. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

TextField Model Field is best for storing product information.

`name = models.TextField()`

you can learn more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField)